# Ruby send string variable as hex

Tags: ruby, string, hex

How am I to express variable as hex to send like-

```
a='00'
write("\x#{a}") => 0x00
```

Trying to include received string variable into command string of raw data and passed to com port like -

```
cmd="\x45\x#{a}\x01"
Send(cmd)
```

In Ruby

Thanks

Comment: Just using `"0x#{a}"` should work, unless I'm missing something...  Have you tried that?

Comment: Sending "0x#{a}" sends string or 4 bytes "0x00" => 0x30 0x78 0x30 0x30. Looking to convert the string "00" to 0x00

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [String#to_i](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-to_i) function takes a base argument, which default to ten - but you can pass in sixteen instead.  That'll get you the number you want as a number, rather than a string.  From there, you can use the [Integer#chr](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Integer.html#method-i-chr) function to get the value you want - a string containing the character with the binary value represented by the original string.

Comment: See my comment above. The problem is I'm receiving information representing raw data bytes in string format. I have to send that information as raw data. I patched it with -`case a;when '00'; b="\x00".....;end;return b`. Ugly...

Comment: @sbtech - You might be able to chain this with the `chr` function.  For example, in IRB, `'10'.to_i(16).chr` returns `"\020"` (the console shows it in octal, but the value is right).  Is that the format you need?

Comment: Yes! That worked like a charm. Thanks. I had not thought of octal but binary is binary.

Comment: @sbtech - Great!  I've tweaked the answer to include the full process.